# Issue in adding my monitor resolution

Tags: display-resolution

I have an issue in adding my monitor resolution.

[image]

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is a Q&A site. I don't see a question here. Read [ask] then [edit] accordingly and don't forget to include your Distro/version/

Comment: It looks to me like a bug in `xrandr` which you can report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net).

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please don't post screenshots. Please copy and paste and use markdown format to properly format as a block of code in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.